# Filter on conditional formatting in excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, conditional-formatting, styleframe

I have an excel file that has conditional formatting with red color in certain rows one of the columns.
So my file looks like this

[image]

Now I have to apply the filter on the "College" column to delete all the rows that have a red-colored background.

[image]

And save it back to the file.

The code I wrote for this is:

```
dataFrame_file = pd.read_excel(util.comcastFile2Path(), sheet_name='Sheet1')  //comcastFile2Path() gives path of file
def only_cells_with_red_background(cell):
    return cell if cell.style.bg_color in {utils.colors.red, 'FFFF0000'} else np.nan

df=dataFrame_file.style.applymap(only_cells_with_red_background,subset=['College'])
util.mergeFile(dataFrame_file,df,util.comcastFile2Path)
```

And my util class method for merging and saving file looks like this

```
def mergeFile(dataFrame_file, delete_frame, comcastFileName):
    dataFrame_file = dataFrame_file.merge(delete_frame, how='left', indicator=True).query(
        '_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
    saveFile(dataFrame_file,comcastFileName)
```

When I do this the error I get is:

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'pandas.io.formats.style.Styler'> was passed
```

How can I move further with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.read_excel` does not read the style from the Excel file.

Since you tagged the question with [styleframe](/questions/tagged/styleframe) I believe you meant to read the file with `StyleFrame.read_excel(util.comcastFile2Path(), sheet_name='Sheet1', read_style=True)`.

Then you also don't need to use `df.merge`. You can just select the rows with no red background and save the new StyleFrame object:

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, utils

def no_red_background_cell(cell):
    return cell if cell.style.bg_color not in {utils.colors.red, 'FFFF0000'} else np.nan

sf = StyleFrame.read_excel(util.comcastFile2Path(), sheet_name='Sheet1', read_style=True)
sf = StyleFrame(sf.applymap(no_red_background_cell).dropna(axis=(0, 1), how='all'))
sf.to_excel('output.xlsx').save()
```